# css styles work in id, but not in class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply certain styles to a div. This div will be unique in width, padding and other attributes, but there will be many other divs in my site with the same border-radius and opacity styles, (but different widths paddings etc) so I also want to use a class. I find that if I list all the attributes under the div id, it works perfectly, but if I list some under the #selector and others under the .selector, the class selector styles are not applied. I would really like to know why. Is it something that can't be done like this or is it an error in my code?

Thank you!!

Here is the code that doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<section id="container">
    <div id="gallery" class="outline">this is my problem div</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
div#gallery {
display:inline-block;
margin:0 auto;
max-width:100%;
text-align:center;
width:100%;

}

.outline {
background: #212121;
-moz-border-radius:0.5em;
-webkit-border-radius:0.5em;
border-radius:0.5em;
opacity:0.75;
filter:alpha(opacity=7.5);
}
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/zCCRR/  There must be more to it than the code you've posted.

Comment: agreed.  tested in Chrome, Firefox, and IE, and in all of them, I saw attributes from both CSS blocks being applied

Comment: Likely another css selector is taking precedence - best way to debug would be to inspect the element in your preferred browser and see which styles are being applied and in which order.

Comment: thank you very much!!! I guess I was missing something in the original code (maybe a dot or a semicolon or something) but no matter how many times I looked at it and checked it over and over and looked for it, I couldn't see it. I just copied/pasted what I wrote for you here and you were right, it worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

FOR PEOPLE USING VSCODE(live server ) : I faced the same problem yesterday , and I didn't have error in the code , I closed the window and launched live server again , and the class's worked

Comment: It's not an answer, friend :)

Comment: maybe it's not but it could help someone that faced the same problem and wasting time reviewing the code again and again , in my case it was a 600 line of CSS and 800 line of HTML

Comment: Yeah, it's good to share your experience with others. Although, I think it's better to be in the comments.